# Appium - Horizontal Scroll view

Tags: appium

I am using an android app that has horizontal scroll view, how to traverse through each of these items inside the horizontal scroll view using appium . The items change dynamically, so using textview won't work. Is there any method to get the length of the horizontal scroll view and traverse using loop?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i deal with a similar situation:
assuming you want to scroll down to a specific **textView** element.

```
while(!driver.findElement(By.id("textViewId").isdisplayed){
 scrollDownManually();
}


public void scrollDownManually() {
        Dimension size = Android.driver.manage().window().getSize();
        int starty = (int) (size.height * 0.80);
        int endy = (int) (size.height * 0.20);
        int startx = size.width / 2;

        Android.driver.swipe(startx, starty, startx, endy, 1000);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always perform swipe actions

```
TouchAction t=new TouchAction(driver);
//long press, for atleast 1 sec first and move the object            
WebElement First=driver.findElementByXPath("//*[**First Element**]");        
WebElement second=driver.findElementByXPath("//*[**Second Element**]");
t.longPress(longPressOptions().withElement(element(First)).withDuration(ofSeconds(3))).moveTo(element(second)).release().perform();
```